# JavaScript reduce can't handle Math functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reduce, higher-order-functions

I'm trying an obvious task:

```
var maxVal = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ].reduce( Math.max, 0 );
```

and get:

```
NaN
```

as the result. To make it work I have to make an anonymous function this way:

```
var maxVal = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ].reduce( function ( a, b ) { 
                                           return Math.max(a, b);
                                       }, 0 );
```

Could someone tell me **why**? Both are functions that take two arguments and both return one value. What's the difference?

Another example could be this:

```
var newList = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]].reduce( Array.concat, [] );
```

The result is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 0, #1=[1, 2, 3], #2=[4, 5, 6], 4, 5, 6, 1, #1#, #2#]
```

I can run this example in node.js only under this shape (Array has no concat in node.js v4.12, which I use now):

```
var newList = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]].reduce( [].concat, [] );
```

and then get this:

```
[ {}, {}, 1, 2, 3, 0, [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], 4, 5, 6, 1, [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ] ]
```

And why is that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The function passed to `reduce` [takes more than 2 arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Parameters):

- `previousValue`
- `currentValue`
- `index`
- `array`

`Math.max` will evaluate **all** arguments and return the highest:

```
Math.max(1, 2, 3, 4) === 4;
```

So in case of passing `Math.max` to `reduce`, it will return the highest value from the 4 arguments passed, of which one is an array. Passing an array will make `Math.max` return `NaN` because an array is not a number. This is in the specs (15.8.2.11):

> Given zero or more arguments, calls ToNumber on each of the arguments and returns the largest of the resulting values.
>
> ...
>
> If any value is NaN, the result is NaN

`ToNumber` will return `NaN` for an array.

So reducing with `Math.max` will return `NaN` in the end.

Comment: An alternative solution to do it can be: Math.max.apply(null, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

Comment: Thx!! It's clear now. I edited my question, but you answer both of my problems with reduce!! It's cool now.

Comment: What a bunch of crap, and an unbelievable lack of foresight. How did ECMA *not* see `reduce(max)` as a thing that people would write? They need to step up their functional game.

Answer (score 4):

Since `Math.max` accepts multiple arguments, you can just convert the array to a parameter list via the `apply` function.

```
var maxVal = Math.max.apply(Math, [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]);
```

[See warnings here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#apply_and_built-in_functions) on limitations of this technique.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to reduce an array to its max value:

```
var maxVal = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ].reduce(function(a,b){return a>b?a:b});
```

(illustrating how reduce works, not that it is the best way to get the max number from an array)