# Why does [...].reduce(Math.min,0) return NaN?

Tags: javascript

I am a little confused as to why `Math.min` is yielding a `NaN` in the following example.

```js
console.log([].reduce(Math.min,0)); // prints 0
console.log([-1].reduce(Math.min,0)); // prints -1
console.log([-1,-2].reduce(Math.min,0)); // prints NaN?????
```

Tests with longer Arrays of numbers also yield `NaN`.

My expectations are that `[....].reduce(Math.min,0)` will yield the lower number in the Array starting from 0 (assume they are negative numbers).

Comment: `Math.min()` takes an arbitrary number of parameters, and `.reduce` passes more than just 2.

Comment: `Math.min` accepts multiple arguments, the `reduce` callback is called with multiple arguments, like the _index_ and the _array_ itself. You don’t want those in your `Math.min` call. Why not just use `Math.min(...array, 0)`?

Comment: That make sense, but why does it work for `[-1]`?

Comment: @Xufox I never thought of doing that :) There to many ways to be clever. Sometimes it's an art form.

Comment: @cgTag In the first case, the call to `Math.min` effectively looks like this: `Math.min(0, -1, 0, [-1])`, which is `initialValue, currentValue, index, array`. All of them are numbers, except `[-1]`, which needs to be converted to a primitive value. It is coerced to a string first: `String([-1])` is `"-1"`, then it’s coerced to a number: `Number("-1")` is `-1`; this works, and you get `-1` as a result. In the second example, the `array` is `[-1, -2]`. Its string representation is `"-1,-2"` which _cannot_ be converted to a number, thus you get `NaN`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript reduce can't handle Math functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767748)